# Resolve singleton object from several threads

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I want to resolve the same object from different threads. But when I dispose (teardown) an object in one thread and resolve it in another thread, I get two different objects, although the object needs to be a singleton across the whole application. The LifetimeManager is a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager which should behave like a singleton, but it doesn't when I have several threads.

What can I do about this issue?

More details:
I think a part of the problem might be, that I register a new type mapping in one thread. Although I have synchronized the call the UnityContainer seems to hold a reference on the item built up before and provides it to the thread which calls resolve. The thread which registers the new type mapping gets the new item just fine.

Comment: Stupid question, but let's just clear up something: is the container shared across all threads or does each thread have its own instance?

Comment: There's only one container set up for the whole application.

Comment: Can you please add some more detail, good to add a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` holds the resolved instance just in private non static field. It is often called singleton but real meaning is singleton per lifetime manager instance. Once you register type again it will get new instance of `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` and this instance of lifetime manager will hold its own instance of resolved type.

Simple: Two different type registrations = two different "singletons".

Comment: Thanks, that means I need to implement my own lifetime manager.